# How to add multiple inputs in one line for an if statement in a while loop for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a simple shell program that accepts commands from the user for a restaurant. But I'm very confused on how to accept multiple inputs from the user so that the shell can read it and then interpret it to follow with the called function.

```
iinventory = {
    "apple": 0,
    "beets": 0,
    "carrots": 0}

total=20

def handle_commands():
    keep_going=True
    while keep_going:
        command=input("$ ").split()
        var1=input()
        var2=input()
        if command == var1 + var2:
            var1="loadrecipefile"
            var2=recipe_file
            loadrecipefile(recipe_file)
        elif command == "printrecipes":
            printrecipes()
        elif command == "printiinventory":
            printiinventory()
        elif command == "printmoney":
            printmoney()
        elif command == "preparedish ":
            command=input().split(" ")
            preparedish(recipe_name)
        elif command == "buyingredient ":
            command=input().split(" ")
            buyingredient(name, number)
        elif command == "quit":
            keep_going=False
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry that is not an acceptable command")
    return 

def loadrecipefile (recipe_file):
    infile=open(recipe_file)
    Linelist=infile.readlines()
    for line in Linelist:
        wordList=line.split()
        r1={'apple':int(wordList[1]),'beets':int(wordList[2]),'carrots':int(wordList[3])}
        cookbook={wordList[0]:r1}

def printrecipes():
    for name,ingred in cookbook.items():
        print(name + " " + str(ingred['apple']) + " " + str(ingred['beets']) + " " + str(ingred['carrots']))

def buyingredient(name, number:int):
    global total
    total_spent=0
    if number + total_spent > total:
        print("Not enough cash!")
    iinventory[name] += number
    total -= number

def printiinventory():
    print(iinventory['apple'],iinventory['beets'],iinventory['carrots'])

def printmoney():
    print(total)

def CanPrepareDish(recipe_name):
    recipe = cookbook[recipe_name]
    for ingred in recipe:
        if ingred not in iinventory:
            return False
        if iinventory[ingred] < recipe[ingred]:
            return False
    return True

def preparedish(recipe_name):
    if not CanPrepareDish(recipe_name):
        print("Not enough ingredients")
    else:
        recipe = cookbook[recipe_name]
        for ingred in recipe:
            iinventory[ingred] -= recipe[ingred]
        if recipe_name in iinventory:
            iinventory[recipe_name] +=1
        else:
            iinventory[recipe_name] = 1
            print("Dish prepared")

handle_commands()
```

For example, if the user was to execute:

```
$ buyingredient apple 5
```

The program should be able to accept all 3 of the different inputs then split the inputs by the spaces and then execute the function, buyingredient. I don't know how to accept the multiple inputs in one line of command.

AND, for the `printrecipes()` function, I want it to print the cookbook that is created in the loadrecipefile function but it says that the cookbook is not defined so how do I use the cookbook from the loadrecipefile function for the `printrecipes()`. The cookbook is a dictionary and I've tried making the `cookbook={}` outside of the function but `printrecipes()` just prints it as blank rather than printing the cookbook that was created in loadrecipe file

```
def loadrecipefile (recipe_file):
    infile=open(recipe_file)
    Linelist=infile.readlines()
    for line in Linelist:
        wordList=line.split()
        r1={'apple':int(wordList[1]),'beets':int(wordList[2]),'carrots':int(wordList[3])}
        cookbook={wordList[0]:r1}
        print(cookbook)
```

So for example, using the above code, it would print the cookbook:

```
loadrecipefile("recipe_file.txt")
{'Recipe1': {'apple': 1, 'beets': 4, 'carrots': 3}}
{'Recipe2': {'apple': 0, 'beets': 2, 'carrots': 4}}
{'Recipe3': {'apple': 3, 'beets': 0, 'carrots': 1}}
{'Recipe4': {'apple': 2, 'beets': 1, 'carrots': 0}}
```

and with `printrecipes()` it should print

```
Recipe1 1 4 3
Recipe2 0 2 4
Recipe3 3 0 1
Recipe4 2 1 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into the `argparse` module.

Answer (score 0):

This

> ```
> command=input("$ ").split()
> var1=input()
> var2=input()
> ```

asks for 3 user inputs. The first one is split like you seem to want to.

> ```
> if command == var1 + var2:
>     var1="loadrecipefile"
>     var2=recipe_file
>     loadrecipefile(recipe_file)
> ```

is never going to happen, as `command` is a list (due to splitting) and `var1` and `var2` are strings.

---

You can create a mapping from *input command* to *funciton call* as a `dict`, check for enough parameters and proceed:

Create some function stubbs that do what need to be done (just printing here):

```
def buySomething(what, howMany):
    print(what,howMany) 

def listThem(ingredient):
    print("Listing: ", ingredient)

def searchRecepie(receipt):
    print("Searching for:", receipt)

def error(line):
    print ("An error occured, try again", line)

def qexit():
    exit(0)
```

Create parsing and mapping:

```
# create mapping what input maps to what function call        
mapping = {"buy":buySomething, 
           "list":listThem,
           "search":searchRecepie,
           "q":qexit}

# create mapping how many params are needed for each function
numParams = {"buy":2, "list":1,"search":1, "q":0}

while True:

    # split the input, extract the command
    choices = input("$ ").strip().lower().split()

    command = choices[0]

    # see if the command is mapped, if not, default to use error function
    callMe = mapping.get(command,error)

    if callMe != error:
        # check if exactly enough params given, if not, use error function
        if len(choices)-1 != numParams.get(command,-1): # cant have -2, this 
            error(choices)
            continue # back to start of 'while True:' scope

        # call the function with params, unpack list without the command
        callMe(*choices[1:])
    else:
        callMe(choices) # this is the error function with the params given
```

Output:

```
$ buy apple 5
apple 5
$ list 9
Listing:  9
$ search popsickle
Searching for: popsickle
$ buy nothing
An error occured, try again ['buy', 'nothing'] # wrong amount of params error
$ cook me
An error occured, try again ['cook', 'me'] # unmapped command error 
$ q
```

You should probably create different (better suited) error function for "not in list of commands" and "not enough / too much params provided"

---

Read about user input validation in this great Q/A: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)